# Unix: redirect output to text redactor using pipe

Tags: unix, pipe

I want `ls -lh | nano` be executed and nano being opened with the list of directories and files but instead I get message:

```
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM   
Buffer written to nano.save.5
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What if you say `ls -lh | nano -`? The `-` after `nano` tells it to use stdin.

Comment: @fedorqui, thanks! this makes it work